# Check a word whether it has letter in the start and at the end

Tags: php, preg-match

Suppoch i have have some words. and i have to check them whether it has "RX" in the start and "CD" in the end.

For example 
I have this "RX3!Pl6HxTCD".

What i have tried is bellow

```
$subject = "RX3!Pl6HxTCD";
$pattern = '/^CD/';
preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,10), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
```

What i got is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => CD [1] => 0 ) )
```

I want to check the first 2 letters and the last 2 letters of the word. And the number of letters may be increase.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `'/^RX.*CD$/s'` or (probably better since it rules out a `CD` at the final newline) `'/^RX.*CD$/sD'`

Comment: where in the pattern ?

Comment: It is the pattern :)

Comment: I think i should remove the substr for now.

Comment: Yes, `if (preg_match('/^RX.*CD$/sD', $subject, $matches))  { print_r($matches); }`

Comment: and if i want to get the value between "RX" and "!", what i have to do. Sorry i want get the idea. So i am asking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177327/discussion-between-ranjit-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: That is a different question, although a dupe of many questions here on SO. `'/RX\K[^!]+/'` or `'/RX(.*?)!/'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not `substr` the string if you want to check both the start and end of the string.

Use

```
if (preg_match('/^RX.*CD$/sD', $subject, $matches)) { 
    print_r($matches); 
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/knKYAR).

The pattern will match

- `^` - start of string
- `RX` - `RX` substring
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `CD` - `CD` substring
- `$` - end of string.

Due to `s` modifier, `.` will also match line breaks, and with `D`, there will be no match if `CD` is followed with a newline, LF, at the end of the string.

However, you may also use a non-regex approach:

```
if (substr($subject, 0, 2) === 'RX' && substr($subject, -2) === 'CD') {
    echo "$subject\n";
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/KipeDr).